# Pandas Seaborn FacetGrid same x labels on every plot, though different y values

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to display FacetGrid with barplots so that it displays data of yellow_cards count (y) and team name (x), divided by different football leagues (other plots should show other leagues, and other team names). The data is being counted correctly but the display shows only the first league on every plot.

Here's the code snippet i'm using to build the FacetGrid:

```
df_alt2_teams = df_alt2.groupby(['league', 'squad'])['cards_yellow', 'cards_red'].sum().reset_index()
df_alt2_teams = df_alt2_teams.sort_values(by=['cards_yellow', 'cards_red'], ascending=True)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_alt2_teams, col='league', height=8, aspect=4)
g = g.map(sns.barplot, 'squad', 'cards_yellow', palette="flare", data=df_alt2_teams)
g.set(ylim=(0, 50))
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

the data differs, but labels don't

data example:

```
index   league          squad       cards_red   cards_yellow
52      Ligue 1         Strasbourg  1.0         2.0
57      Premier League  Brighton    1.0         3.0
```

Comment: Can you post data example?

Comment: sure, added in edit

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need ordered bars, you can directly plot the dataframe and let seaborn do all the calculations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

#test data generation 
import numpy as np
n=30
np.random.seed(123)
df_alt2 = pd.DataFrame({"index": np.arange(n), 
                        "league": "Ligue 1", 
                        "squad": np.random.choice(list("ABCDXYZ"), n), 
                        "cards_red": np.random.randint(0, 3, n),
                        "cards_yellow": np.random.randint(0, 5, n)})
df_alt2.loc[:, "league"][df_alt2.squad.isin(list("XYZ"))] = "Premier League"
                 
g = sns.catplot(data=df_alt2, x="squad", y="cards_yellow", col="league", 
                kind="bar", estimator=sum, ci=None, sharex=False)

g.set(ylim=(0, 20))
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

I would not know how to convince seaborn to order the bars by value. So in this case,
you might have to revert to your precalculation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

#test data generation 
import numpy as np
n=30
np.random.seed(123)
df_alt2 = pd.DataFrame({"index": np.arange(n), 
                        "league": "Ligue 1", 
                        "squad": np.random.choice(list("ABCDXYZ"), n), 
                        "cards_red": np.random.randint(0, 3, n),
                        "cards_yellow": np.random.randint(0, 5, n)})
df_alt2.loc[:, "league"][df_alt2.squad.isin(list("XYZ"))] = "Premier League"
                 

df_alt2_teams = df_alt2.groupby(['league', 'squad'])['cards_yellow', 'cards_red'].sum().reset_index()
df_alt2_teams = df_alt2_teams.sort_values(by=['cards_yellow', 'cards_red'], ascending=True)

g = sns.catplot(data=df_alt2_teams, x="squad", y="cards_yellow", col="league", kind="bar", sharex=False)

g.set(ylim=(0, 20))
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]